# Set frame(size) UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

My main screen have:
`UITabViewController` (content 3 UIViewController). each `UIViewController` has a UITableViewController.
Now i want to set frame of `UITableViewController`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to set frame of UITableViewController... if you want to put a table in your UIViewController, add a tableView in your UIViewController.. you may then set the frame of your tableView.

Comment: what about setting the frame of the tableViewController's view? i'd like to override loadView or something and change the size of the frame of my table View controller's view and then possibly set a constraint to keep it pinned to the right.

Comment: i opted to just change the UITableViewController to a UIViewController that contains a table view and i can size the table view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As no instance of `UIViewController` has a frame property, your question technically makes no sense. Please spend more time reading through Apple's documentation, all you need is there and early on to. Pay some regard to `UIView` and `UIViewController`. [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) is a good place to start. We've all had to start there.